# What if integration testing makes more sense than unit testing for a certain method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

I don't want to spam you with a ton of code, but please have a quick look at this boiler-plate method:

In this scenario let's say I have a `ProcessingText.py` file (class) that I finished its unit testing, including the methods `setTextToClean(text)` and `getCleanedText()`.

And I have another file, `UI.py` (a class also), that has the following `handle_text(text)`:

*UI.py*

```py
# UI Class
 def handle_text(self, res):  
        self.processingTextObj.setTextToClean(res)
        return self.processingTextObj.getCleanedText()
```

**The Question:**

- Looking at that method, to me, I believe that time-wise, this makes more sense to be integration-tested. If I were to unit test it, I would mock the `processingTextObj` along with the two used methods, but would that be advisable? Just for the sake of not leaving any method without being unit-tested?

I've used mocking before for decoupling dependencies while unit-testing, but it made sense before because what have been mocked were just some parts, where a bit of logic in the actual method remained. Here, for this method, I can't see a point in unit testing.

**NOTE**

My plan was to create a unit-test AND an integration-test scripts for  `ProcessingText.py` and for `UI.py` as well (since both of them have external dependencies within each class methods), is this approach wrong? and if `handle_text()` didn't need any unit-testing, I would still need to write an integration test for it, correct? (I know that I should not be asking more than one question, my bad)

Please correct my understanding if I'm wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `setTextToClean` should be the method being unit tested, not `handle_text`.  handle_text is just a pass-through method; it doesn't contain any logic, so there is no need to unit-test it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've already unit-tested ```setTextToClean``` as I mentioned, does that I mean that the ```UI.py``` should not have any unit-testing scripts? and should I integration-test it (specifically ```handle_text```) ?

Comment: I don't generally unit-test methods that don't contain any logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need unit test if I already have integration test?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204786/do-i-need-unit-test-if-i-already-have-integration-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handle text function is just calling another function in processing text object so it is not worth testing in unit and integration.

You instead test processing text functions (set text to clean in your code) in unit test, and the entrypoint of the ui class.

Comment: the entry method of the ui class is to be integration-tested, correct?

Comment: @AhmedAlhallag that's correct

Answer (score 1):

**Unit test** is helpful to verify your code path in individual component works as you expect, and it is faster to locating the potential bugs in smaller piece. Here there may be two parts that worth (unit) testing:

- The logic inside `setTextToClean`, in which you `assert` some fields are expected after this `set` method is being called,
- The logic in your code somewhere (a method `A`) that `handle_text` is properly called, in which you `verify` either `handle_text` or `setTextToClean` is being invoked `x` times as the logic inside `A` expects.

Another thing worth testing in unit test is to verify the capability of handling several code paths other than happy case (e.g., how the exception case is addressed and handled by the code logic within individual component).

**Integration test** verifies several components (external dependencies of your `UI` and `processingText` as you mentioned ) are working together as expected. In your case it verifies the UI workflow responses correctly with the input request rather than tests on a specific passing-through method .